# How to disable Entry Box in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Anyone knows the command to disable the entry box in Tkinter?
(Meaning we cant type anything in the ListBox)

Answer (score 2):

Change the state of the Text widget to DISABLED:

```
text.config(state=DISABLED)
```

more ref [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#patterns)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`state=DISABLED`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).